# Calling Server Side Method in Server Control or Calling service directly from javascript through reference made in Project

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

I have a server control (one which creates a dll file which is later referenced by the websites to use the control). Previously, for ajax requests the service was directly called from javascript exposing the actual service path which is a very big issue. Now I have created a service reference in my project through which I am now supposed to get the data. Is there any way that javascript can call a public function from the server control or call the service  through the reference made in the project? I have a project similar to what is described at [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386450%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx). The magic is hidden in

```
System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a Client side language while .NET code executes on server side. JavaScript can't call a ASP.NET server control Although there are some workaround like calling ASP.NET web method(methodHoneyTrap) through json and then calling another web method (methodActualService) in exposed web method (methodHoneyTrap).

your actual code lies in  methodActualService and methodHoneyTrap will call methodActualService.

---

```
 $.ajax  (
{
  type: "POST",
  url: "MethodInvokeWithJQuery.aspx/methodHoneyTrap",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  async: true,
  cache: false,
  success: function
);
```

Comment: It is actually a server control and can not have aspx files in it. And I cant force the control user to add an aspx file in every project it is to be used.

Comment: how can you call a user control directly. I am afraid its not possible

Comment: I am just looking for a way to hide my service call

Comment: It turns out it is possible. Will post my answer as soon as I get time.

Comment: sure..would be interesting to know

Comment: I have answered the question.